# Debian pure-ftpd, Restrict access

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, ftp

I am running Debian Wheezy, with ISPConfig 3, plus ModSecurity and I would like to restrict access to ftp to specific IP(s) globally (not to specific ftp users only), that can be either 127.0.0.1 or one I would manually add later. I would also like to completely disable ftp access from the web, but allow only from ftp-client software (if that is possible).

The idea of closing firewall ports is not what I want. I know I can do this setting some firewall rule though, but that is not what I currently need. I have managed to do this for example on phpmyadmin inside it's .conf file, but unfortunately I cannot find any configuration to alter for pure-ftpd in my system.

Restricting web-ftp access maybe possible by adding some rule in apache2 conf, but I am not sure how to write such a rule.

Thanks to everyone that can help
cheers

Answer (score 0):

PureFTPD doesn't use .conf files by default, instead you specify options or switches at launch.  You can however get it to parse a file, information on the PureFTPD site here;

http://download.pureftpd.org/pub/pure-ftpd/doc/README.Configuration-File

There's a sample conf file in the Github repo;

https://github.com/jedisct1/pure-ftpd/blob/master/configuration-file/pure-ftpd.conf.in

I think you want to use the

> allow

command in the config, more info here;

http://doc.ctrlaltdel.ch/serveur/proftpd/reference.html#Allow

So you'd do something like;

```
<Limit LOGIN>
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2 [etc]
Deny from all
</Limit>
```

That would deny all clients except those in the allow list.

Comment: thanks for your reply and information, the `limit LOGIN` though will deny login, what I want to do is return forbidden to ANY connection except the IP(s) specified, not only logins. Thanks.

Comment: I would have thought a Firewall would be your only option after looking at the PureFTPd documentation - perhaps UFW? (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW)

Comment: thanks for your help, ispconfig3 uses bastille and additionally I use mod_security and maybe in any of the 2 I can set some rule to do this if there is no other solution through a configuration file. I am currently checking the github conf file for such a thing.

Comment: creating a `/etc/pure-ftpd.conf` is very interesting but unfortunately my system does not have `pure-config.pl` or `pure-config.py` in order to run those commands described in the README.Configuration-File you gave me.

Comment: Just clone them from the Github repo and then use them

Comment: I tried that, created the `/etc/pure-ftpd.conf` but it does not get read by the system even after reboot. The command `./pure-config.pl /etc/pure-ftpd.conf` cannot work once `pure-config.pl` is missing, plus there is no existing path `/usr/local/sbin/pure-ftpd`.

Comment: I would be tempted to use ProFTPD, but I will delete my answer as I don't think it's helped you?

Comment: no do not delete it it helped me and you have helped me, I jsut cannot upvote yet. I will try edit the `/etc/default/pure-ftpd-common`